# Explaining a list function in python

Tags: python

I have this line of code, it puts the english words in a text line (in this case archer and bowman) into a list and uses the integer of the number of words (02 in this case) to figure out how many words are in the line

```
line = 09824747 18 n 02 archer 0 bowman 0 003 @ 09640897 n 0000 ~ 10290474 n 0000 ~ 10718145 n 0000
L = line.split()
word = L[4:4 + 2 * int(L[3]):2]
print(word)
```

This prints out `['archer', 'bowman']`

I want to use the line of code that assigns the words to a list in another way, i want to assign the 8 digit numbers that appear after the '@' symbol to a different list.

I have got the code that gets the amount of 8 digit numbers in the file and my efforts so far. (the number of 8 digit figures in this case is 003)

```
pointer_num = re.findall(r'\b\d{3}\b', line)
K = int(pointer_num[0])
before_at, after_at = line.split('@')
S = after_at.split()[0:0 +3 * K:3]
```

S should be the list of 8 digit figures. although this code prints S out as:

```
['09640897', '~', '0000']
```

This is the right number of entries, just the wrong ones. If someone could explain `word = L[4:4 + 2 * int(L[3]):2]` I should be able to correct it myself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`L[4:4 + 2 * int(L[3]):2]` can be understood like this:

`L[3]` returns the fourth element in the list `L` (e.g. '02').

`int(L[3])` returns the `int` of the string, `L[3]` (e.g. 2).

`4 + 2 * int(L[3])` returns an `int`, e.g. 4+2*2=8.

`L[4:8:2]` returns a list consisting of the elements `L[4]` through `L[7]`, skipping by 2. In other words, `[L[4], L[6]]`. In general `L[start:stop:skip]` returns a list which starts with `L[start]`, and ends just before `L[stop]`. Think of `[start, stop)` as a half-open interval. The last number `skip`, causes the list to skip by this number of elements.

The complete rules on how Python slicing works for sequence types are explained in [Notes 3,4,5 here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq).

Comment: `S = after_at.split()[0:0 +4 * K:4]` this works now! excellent

Answer (score 1):

`L[3]` is `02`.

`int(L[3])` is `2`

`4 + 2 * int(L[3])` is `8`

`L[4:4 + 2 * int(L[3]):2]` is `L[4:8:2]` which means items of `L` from index `4` included  up to index `8` excluded, with steps of `2`

`L[4]` is `'archer'` and `L[6]` is `'bowman'`